# Disable form elements in jQuery Mobile and update style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm not able to apply the disabled style after I disable my form elements. If I press F5 to refresh the page, the style is applied... What is wrong here?

```
$("#frm input").prop("disabled", true);
$("#frm input").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("ui-disabled");
  $(this).trigger("refresh");
});
```

jQuery Mobile 1.4.0

**EDIT**

This works, but then I have to have a loop for each ui-class.....

```
$("#frm .ui-checkbox").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("ui-disabled");                  
});
```

Comment: `$("input").textinput("disable");`

Comment: At the moment there is no textinput. I have flipswitches, radiobuttons, and checkboxes... each type is in a <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> or <div data-role="fieldcontain">

Comment: Do you want to disable all of them at once? or specific ones?

Comment: All at one. I can disable them with my loop. But the style doesn't change

Comment: Hm, this worked , but not so efficient.... -> $(".ui-checkbox").addClass("ui-state-disabled");

Comment: I dont know why `$("#ID").controlgroup("disable")` not working. Anyway, this is faster `$("[data-role=controlgroup]").addClass("ui-state-disabled");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without looping, all you need is to add `ui-state-disabled` to *controlgroup* if you want to *disable* all contents at once.

```
$(".selector").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UANtg/)**

Comment: Worked like a charm :)